# How to create a see-more/Read-more feature requiring only anchors in the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a site which will be maintained by not so tech savvy people, and I need to be able to give them the ability to add "see-more" anchors which use Jquery slide up/down to reveal their content.

My code works well for a single instance of the read more, but when there are multiple instances of this, it gets fairly screwed up.

**javascript/jquery**

```
$(".see-more").nextUntil(".see-less").wrapAll("<div class='see-more-content'></div>");


$(".see-less").hide();
var count= 1
/*
$(".see-more-content").each(function(){
    var count= count+1;
    $(this).data("count",count);
    console.log(count);
});
*/

$(".see-more-content").slideUp(0);



$(".see-more").click(function(){

    $(".see-more-content").slideToggle();
    $(".see-more").hide();
    $(".see-less").show();

});
$(".see-less").click(function(){
    $(".see-more-content").slideToggle();
    $(".see-less").hide();
    $(".see-more").show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="see-more">See More...</a>
<ul>
<li>Advanced Elastic search Technology </li>
<li>Document Text Search</li>
<li>Embed Code Web Publishing for Images, Video &amp; PDFs</li>
<li>Video Management with HTML5 Full</li>
<li>Previews On the Fly Conversions and Transcoding</li>
<li>Print on Demand</li>
<li>Stylized Collections (Lightboxes/Galleries)</li>
<li>Alerts and Notifications</li>
<li>Comments, Ratings and Favorites</li>
<li>WordPress and Drupal CMS Integrations</li>
<li>Dropbox Integration</li>
<li>Asset Level Performance Analytics • Site Activity Analytics Dashboard</li>
<li>Unlimited Custom User Access Levels</li>
<li>Integrated Content Contribution and Workflow</li>
<li>Personal Profile Management</li>
<li>Mobile App and Site&nbsp;</li>
<li>Watermarking</li>
<li>Rights Management</li>
<li>All New Feature Releases3</li>
</ul>
<a class="see-less">See Less...</a></div>
```

**What I want to happen:** 
I want everything between the anchor with class see-more and anchor with class see-less, to get wrapped in a div, which when the anchor for see-more is clicked that div jquery slides down, when see-more is clicked, and slides up when see-less is clicked.

**What is happening:**
It works perfect when there is only one instance of see-more and see-less in a page. https://jsfiddle.net/TheWebTech/by3LsLuu/

When there are multiple instances of see-more and see-less in the html, the contents of all see-more+see-less blocks after the first instance are all moved/wrapped into the first block instances of the see-more see-less blocks get added.

https://jsfiddle.net/TheWebTech/by3LsLuu/4/

How do I prevent everything from being wrapped into the first instance of the see-more see-less block and instead have each one get wrapped separately?

Bonus but not really required: how can I make each see-more section slide up/down separately from eachother?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to keep the layout the same, you can use `.prev()` and `.next()` jQuery methods to determine which selector group you're referring too. Here's an updated fiddle with two instances:

https://jsfiddle.net/szva79d6/1/

First, I've made it so that your wrapping function applies to each selector individually, like so:

```
$(".see-more").each(function() { 
    $(this).nextUntil(".see-less")
           .wrapAll("<div class='see-more-content'></div>");
});
```

What I've done in the two event methods is to make each event only act on the previous or next siblings, so that your events are properly delegated to each dynamically wrapped element.

```
$(".see-more").click(function() {
  var $more    = $(this),
      $content = $more.next(".see-more-content"),
      $less    = $content.next(".see-less");

  $content.slideToggle();
  $more.hide();
  $less.show();

});

$(".see-less").click(function() {
  var $less    = $(this),
      $content = $less.prev(".see-more-content"),
      $more    = $content.prev(".see-more");

  $content.slideToggle();
  $less.hide();
  $more.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target specific to itself, try this:

```
$(".see-more").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".see-more-content").slideToggle(); // find next content and show
    $(this).hide(); // hide the see more button
    $(this).nextAll('.see-less').first().show(); // show the next see less button

});

$(".see-less").click(function(){
    $(this).prev(".see-more-content").slideToggle();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prevAll(".see-more").first().show();
});
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tn08m5y/)

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for taking a crack at it. I've tried swapping my click code for yours but it doesn't seem to work right.
I've popped it into this fiddle and it seems to just hide the see-more link.

https://jsfiddle.net/TheWebTech/by3LsLuu/5/

Comment: Just looking at fiddle now - it's close just needs tweaking

Comment: Works as planned now I think